# Apple Music sharing

Tags: music

Sharing Family Apple Music, can my bother use his HomePod to do the same as me, as I do on my HomePod, at his home with his HomePod, like ask Siri to play his music on sharing iCloud.

HomePod works on iCloud so if pod connected to there iCloud play there music iCloud?
They say each person uses there iCloud for there music on family share.?
At home, I ask Siri to play on my HomePod, at the moment am just on a single Apple Music, if it’s possible I’ll upgrade to family!.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but this is what I think is the gist of it:

- Both you and your brother have a home pod at different locations/houses (not same wifi/local network)
- You and your brother have an apple music account with your music in an iCloud library

Your **question** (I *think*):

- Can we interchangeably play music from each others account (meaning library) on either home pod when creating an Apple Music family account?

Then the answer is: **Yes**, sort of.
When creating an Apple music family account, you will still have two seperate accounts, therefore two different libraries. Yet, when each of you create a playlist with each other favorite music/whole library, you can play their music. 
I don't really see the use of it though, since you both have access to all of apple musics songs.

Be **careful** though, not to mix the following things: **Apple Music library** (iCloud library) and iTunes library **home sharing**. The second one only works on your home network with the Remote app and you don't need a family account/any account associated to the owner's account of the library. The first one though only shares your library with devices connected to that Apple Music account, but can also be shared on your home network with home sharing.